# IP Transit Using GCP compute instance?

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, bandwidth, bgp

If I announce my IP space on GCP compute engine and connect to GCP via a Dedicated interconnect, as the inbound transfer on GCP is free, can I use GCP as my inbound IP Transit

Answer (score 1):

No, because Google won't onward announce your AS and prefixes.

Comment: So, if I have an instance, and I announce my IP space, then the traffic will flow back through my interconnect and go out via my Transit? I don't quite get this bring your own IP thing on GCP.

Comment: BGP on GCP is only iBGP, it's for dynamic routing between your on premise network and your GCP network.